# htaccess 301 redirect with per-user directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to get a 301 redirect to work with per-user directories (example.com/~user) but every redirect goes to the user folder on the new domain (example.com/~user redirects to newdomain.com/~user and I want it to go to example2.com/)

here's my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://sites.google.com/site/newsite/$[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://sites.google.com/site/newsite/" [r=301,nc]
```

Whenever the original url is hit, the new site gets ~user appended to the end, so I get sites.google.com/site/newsite/~user/ and I just want to remove the ~user part.  Any help?

Comment: What does your original 301 redirect look like? The rewrite code you have will never work because the HOST is only the hostname.

Comment: I originally had Redirect 301 / https://sites.google.com/site/newsite/ and that gives the same issue.  both ways DO go to the new domain, just with ~user appended to the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^site/newsite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sites.google.com/site/newsite/ [R=301,L]
```

or you can simply use mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(?!site/newsite/) https://sites.google.com/site/newsite/
```

The reason why `Redirect` includes the `~user` bit is because it redirects everything *after* the path in the first parameter. So

```
Redirect / /dest
```

Redirects, `/`, `/dir/`. `/file.php`, etc. Anything that starts with `/`.

Comment: this worked.  Thanks for the help!  Still new to web server management so This was a lesson